# Issue in sending POST data from Postman

Tags: php, html, postman

[image]I'm new to Postman.

I have a login page in php/html. In this, data is sent through POST via html form.

But when I send POST data from Postman, it is not sent at all.

On the contrary where I change $_POST["phone_number"] to $_GET["phone_number"] in php side, its working fine.

Can anybody tell why is this happening and any possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that your form post method is POST instead of GET

Comment: Can you show use some code?

Comment: @NipunTyagi it is POST on postman side

Comment: @WasteD php code?

Comment: What did you type into Postman? A screenshot is required here

Comment: @Observer The html form and the php code

Comment: @JuanMendes updated

Comment: @WasteD php side it's just accepting post variable

Answer (score 1):

Select "urlencoded" from postman while  you are sending request throught it.
Also set method as a post and use url like "aaaa.php".